# inserting from textbox and datagridview at sametime in database

Tags: c#, winforms, button, datagridview, textbox

how can I insert data from datagridview and textboxes at same time with one button click in one table. here is my code I use foreachloop to insert from DataGridview but it insert null
any help appreciate.

```
SqlCommand cmd, cmd1, cmd2, cmd3;

con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into sale_detail(sale_bill_number, discount,currency,date) values(@sale_bill_number, @discount ,@currency,@date)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sale_bill_number", billbox.SelectedItem);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount", txtdiscount.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currency", currencyid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePicker.Value.Date);
cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into payment(sdetail,totalprice) values(@sdetail,@totalprice)", con);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdetail", sid);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalprice", txtpayment.Text);
cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into sale(customer) values(@customer)", con);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer", customerid);
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in saleDataGridView.Rows)
{
    string sqlquery = "insert into sale_detail(medicine_id,purchase_rate,quantity)values(@medicine_id,@purchase_rate, @quantity)";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@medicine_id", dr.Cells["شماره مسلسل"].Value);
    // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", saleDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["کشور"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@purchase_rate", dr.Cells["قیمت"].Value);
    // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sale_rate", dr.Cells["قیمت فروش"].Value ??DBNull.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", dr.Cells["تعداد"].Value);
}

if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
{
   if (cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1) {
        if (cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
        {
```

Comment: The _cmd_ inside the foreach loop is executed just one time when you exit the loop. Probably, if you want it executed for each row you need to move the ExecuteNonQuery inside the loop. However the variable _cmd_ is reinitialized inside the loop and everything is reset. So the external query assigned to your _cmd_ variable in the first lines and its parameters will never be executed.

Comment: so what is the solution ??

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing exactly what are you trying to do. First I would execute each SqlCommand when you have completed the parameters. So execute the first cmd and return if the result is not 1. Apply the same logic for cmd1 and cmd2. Inside the loop execute the cmd at each loop. However I suspect that you want to insert everything or, if something fails, you want to insert nothing. If this is the case, then take a look at how the SqlTransaction object works

Comment: what about cmd3? And why that types are different? `insert into sale_detail(sale_bill_number, discount,currency,date)` and `insert into sale_detail(medicine_id,purchase_rate,quantity)`

Comment: I am inserting in tree tables  so i use different cmd comment in one table sale_detail i have to insert from textboxes and datagrid in same time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
using con = new SqlCommand(...);

con.Open();
var tran = con.BeginTransaction();

var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into sale_detail(sale_bill_number, discount,currency,date) values(@sale_bill_number, @discount ,@currency,@date)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sale_bill_number", billbox.SelectedItem);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount", txtdiscount.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currency", currencyid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePicker.Value.Date);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into payment(sdetail,totalprice) values(@sdetail,@totalprice)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdetail", sid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalprice", txtpayment.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into sale(customer) values(@customer)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer", customerid);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in saleDataGridView.Rows)
{
    string sqlquery = "insert into sale_detail(medicine_id,purchase_rate,quantity)values(@medicine_id,@purchase_rate, @quantity)";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@medicine_id", dr.Cells["شماره مسلسل"].Value);
    // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", saleDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["کشور"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@purchase_rate", dr.Cells["قیمت"].Value);
    // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sale_rate", dr.Cells["قیمت فروش"].Value ??DBNull.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", dr.Cells["تعداد"].Value);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

tran.Commit();
```

And wrap the whole thing(apart from the using) in a try catch (I would have done it but I'm on a cellphone; there is no code indent button)  and put `tran.Rollback();` in the catch

Comment: con.CommitTransation and con.RollbackTransaction   are giveing error  , it says sqlconnection does not contain definition for CommitTransaction and Rollbacktransaction.

Comment: it saves null in table

Comment: Make sure that the data you're passing is not null?